# Background img doesn't work css

Tags: html, css, sass

I saw this web design that I wanted to try making.. I've made the header so far and everything works EXCEPT THE BACKGROUND IMAGE.
I have no idea what is wrong with my code .. please tell me what I am doing wrong.
I will put the full scss and the html code

the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>ClassyDays</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<header>
  <h2 id="nav-ico"><i class="fa fa-navicon"></i></h2>
  <div id="warp-h">
  <h1>CLASSY<span class="gray">DAYS</span></h1>
  <h2 class="gray">A classy HTML/Css3 design by <em>my highness</em></h2>
  <button>LEARN MORE</button>
</div>
</header>

<!--intro--><section id="sec1"></section>
<!--features--><section id="sec2"></section>
<!--feat-det--><section id="sec3"></section>
<!--seprate--><section id="sec4"></section>
<!--feat-pic--><section id="sec5"></section>
<!--button-sep--><section id="sec6"></section>
<!--team--><section id="sec7"></section>
<!--login--><section id="sec8"></section>
<!--socail-media--><section id="sec9"></section>
<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my css (scss) code

```
//colors
$black: #353535;
$grey: #a1a9b0;
$darkblue: #242830;
$button: #3dc9b3;
$button-shadow: #309383;

//size
$h1: 2em;
$h2: 1.25em;
$body: 1em;

//font (only one)
$font: 'Lato', sans-serif;


* {

}
body {
  color: $grey;
  font-size: $body;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: $font;
}
.gray {
  color: $grey;
}
h1 {
  color: $black;
  font-size: $h1;
}
h2 {
  color: $black;
  font-size: $h2;

}
header {
  display:block;
  background: url(img/header.png);
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  #nav-ico {
    float: right;
    padding: .5 * $body 7 * $body;
    :hover {
      color: $grey;
    }
  }
  #warp-h {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 4 * $h1;
  }
  button {
    font-family: $font;
    font-size: $body;
    padding: .5 * $body $body;
    margin: 2 * $body;
    border: none;
    border-radius: .5 * $body;
    background: $button;
    border-bottom: 4px solid $button-shadow;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    width: 10.25em;
    height: 3.5em;
  }
}
```

I know I am not making any css link mistake because it basically works on everything ( the color, size, padding and such )
nor do I believe the problem is with the picture or its link, because I have changed its place and the picture itself( I put an image that I used previously in  a project ) but nothing work
I have tried to copy-paste that line many times from the internet just in case I have a spelling mistake but then again I didn't misspell

EDIT: THANK YOU!
to anyone interested, basically I forgot to make the link RELATIVE to the css file and not the website itself

Comment: Did you try to check the full url of image in browser source viewer? Try to add slash before to make path absolute instead of relative.

Comment: check the console and see the error

Comment: Assuming everything is as you've said it is, then it's because `img/header.png` is not correct. Keep in mind the path needs to be relative to the CSS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your background image is not relative to the CSS file...

```
background: url(/img/header.png);
```

This should work if your image is found at your-site.com/img/header.png